# SQL - If Max Return 'True' Else 'False'

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, max, case

I have a query that produces a table like the following:

[image: Current Output]

What I am trying to accomplish is to have it return 'TRUE' if the Appeal ID value is the MAX value for that Product and Year. So the results would look like the following:

[image: Desired Output]

The Part ID is irrelevant but produces duplicate values in the Appeal ID.

I've used the following to at least find the right values:

```
SELECT MAX(AppealID)
    ,ProductID
    ,PartID
    ,Year
FROM (XYZ Tables with Many Joins)
    GROUP BY ProductId,Year,PartID
```

But this obviously only returns those values and I can't add all the other columns I need. I tried any number of different CASE statements,but can't seem to get it to work.  Mostly I get aggregation errors.

Thoughts?

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do this:

```
SELECT 
    ,ProductID
    ,PartID
    ,Year
    ,CASE WHEN MAX(AppealID) OVER (PARTITION BY productid, year) = AppealID THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as MaxCheck
FROM (XYZ Tables with Many Joins)
```

That says to grab the max(appealid) inside of the group of records that match the same `productid` and `year` as this record. Then we just compare to the current record.

Comment: great answer!, just remove the group by altogether.

Comment: @Alex Good catch! I removed the bad `max()` and the `group by`.

Comment: This worked perfectly as is. Thanks JNevill. I have been scratching my head on this for hours. Forgot all about partitions.

Comment: @JNevill, my automatic go to would have been a cross apply, but I like the windowing function solution. Any idea what the performance comparison would be between the two?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock I'm not sure on the performance. I would wager that unless the data is really small, this will be quicker. The result set will first be produced 100% and only then will the window function kick in to play on those results. A cross apply seems like it would get tangles up in the complexity of the query (if the query is very complex than the cross apply has more work to do). Where this window function will scale on top of any complexity and will only get slower as record counts in the result set grow.

Comment: I may be wrong about that though since I've only played with cross apply in a copy/paste manner. I don't generally work on sql servers so it's a little foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to group in a subquery then join to find if max:

```
declare @t table(product_id int, part_id int, appeal_id int, [year] int)
insert into @t values
(1,6,1,2016),
(1,7,1,2016),
(1,6,2,2017),
(1,7,2,2016),
(1,8,3,2016),
(1,8,1,2016);


select t.*, case when m.appeal_id is not null then 'TRUE' else '' end as Max_Check
from 
    @t t
    left join
    (
select MAX(appeal_id) appeal_id, product_id, [YEAR]
from 
    @t
group by product_id, [year]
) m on t.product_id = m.product_id and
t.year = m.year and
t.appeal_id = m.appeal_id
```